# Can I get some help with a line integral? $\int_\Gamma (x^2 + 5y + 7z)dx + (y^2+z+5x)dy + (z^2+7x + y)dz)$

Tags: line-integrals, stokes-theorem

A(0,10, 0), B($3 \sqrt 10, 0, \sqrt10$), C(2, 8, 0) with $\int_\Gamma (x^2 + 5y + 7z)dx + (y^2+z+5x)dy + (z^2+7x + y)dz)$

$\Gamma$  is made from the following segments:

A->B {$ (x,y,z)∈ \Bbb R^3 / x^2+y^2+z^2=100,x-3z=0, x≥0, y≥0$}

[BA] line

From what I understand the A B portion is a quarter of a sphere with the radius of 10 and a plane that goes through the origin and cuts the quarter sphere? So I think I should apply Stokes' Theorem on the first part then I substract from that the second part somehow

Sorry for my bad english and formatting. Thank you for the future insight

Comment: The problem is the point $C$ is neither on the sphere or the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the vector field $\vec F = (x^2 + 5y + 7z, y^2+z+5x, z^2+7x + y)$ is a conservative vector field and its potential function is

$\vec F = \nabla f(x,y,z)$ where $\displaystyle f(x,y,z) = \frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{3} + 5xy + yz + 7zx$.

So the line integral is path independent and it should simply be

$I = f(c) - f(a)$ where $a$ is the starting point and $c$ is the end point.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just a question, is it supposed to be a negative number? From my calculations it was -80

Comment: Yes that is correct. Starting from point A, I get $-80$ too. By the way in your question, after AB, you mention B->A line, that should read B->C?

Comment: Yes, it should have been B->C. It was 11pm on my side and I was too tired to see the mistake. Thank you for your answer!